# How to determine if "over RAM-ing" will work

Tags: laptop, memory, thinkpad

I have earlier had a laptop that officially only supported 8 GB RAM, but which in practice worked with 16 GB RAM.

I am about to upgrade my Lenovo A475. A475 [officially](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_A475/ThinkPad_A475_Spec.PDF) only supports 32 GB, but [this site](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/lenovo/notebook/thinkpad/a-series/a475/) suggests it can be "over RAM'ed" to 64 GB (Is there a technical term for "over RAM'ing"?).

Unfortunately I can find no other evidence supporting this.

How can I confirm (or at least be more sure) that the site is correct? Maybe we know the memory controller in the A475 is also used in machines officially supporting 64 GB? Maybe there are users who have already upgraded to 64 GB?

Comment: If the spec on the manufacturer's website states "Supports up to 32GB" RAM, it's safe to assume the limit is 32GB. I've never heard of adding extra RAM above what the chipset supports, but I would question system stability if adding additional RAM above what the manufacturer states.

Comment: It seems the memory controller on those APU's do support upto 64GB of memory, however there are no guarantees. Since the manufacturer states upto 32GB supported, thats what you should go by.

Comment: In my experience, the "Maximum Supported RAM" for a given product tends to be what is practically feasible at product launch, not what the technical limits might be... Ultimately, you can't be 100% sure without physically putting the RAM in and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your
[CompuRAM link](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/lenovo/notebook/thinkpad/a-series/a475/)
also includes the explanation in the link
[Maximise the maximum?](https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/maximise-the-maximum/)

The article explains that the original manufacturer specifications do not
take into account newer technologies that came out afterward and that
allow exceeding the original specs.

The argument seems persuasive, and is also supported by some other offers
on the internet ([example](https://www.ebay.com/itm/275469609518)).

The [CompuRAM FAQ says](https://www.compuram.biz/faq.htm?cat=C3&q=q16) :

> **Can I send back memory modules when they don’t function in my system?**
>
> Yes.
> In our product database, you only find upgrades that have been
> certificated by us for the designated system. We have an extraordinary
> support, which - in situations with little start-up difficulties -
> reacts quickly and professionally. From experience, in most cases we
> successfully find a solution together by phone or e-mail. In other
> cases, an exchange of the module normally leads to the desired result.
> Please read our blog entry to learn why we can guarantee 100%
> compatible memory modules for your system. In the rare event that you
> cannot use our product due to a defect (dead on arrival), we will of
> course assume the return costs and take care of a free replacement
> delivery.

This seems that you take no risk, although there is one big warning sign
in the fact that reimbursement is not mentioned at all.

In the end, you buy at your own risk.
I believe CompuRAM that they tested this RAM in a Thinkpad A475,
however you can't know if your model is identical to the one that
CompuRAM tested.

Comment: The eBay link is clearly wrong: It links to 4 pcs 16GB modules, but there are only 2 memory slots in the A475. So we still have only a single source saying it will work.